# Putting cursor with 2 tables in a variable in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm still new to oracle pl/sql so please bear with me. How do I put a cursor with 2 tables inside a variable rowtype? Is it possible to put 2 table rowtypes inside a single variable?

```
PROCEDURE testproc IS
l_var  table1%ROWTYPE;

CURSOR cur1 IS
Select *
From table1, table2
where table1.id = table2.id;

BEGIN

OPEN cur1;
LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO l_var;
```

Comment: Yes, I do it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `l_var` should be from the `cur1` row type:

```
PROCEDURE testproc IS

CURSOR cur1 IS
select *
from table1, table2
where table1.id = table2.id;

l_var  cur1%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

OPEN cur1;
LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO l_var;
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I already tried that. It says that the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed

Comment: It should be okay. Can the `select *` be the issue since the `id` for example is ambiguous?

Answer (score 1):

```
PROCEDURE testproc IS

CURSOR cur1 IS
SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table2.field1, table2.field2
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id;

l_var cur1%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

OPEN cur1
WHILE cur1%ISOPEN LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO l_var

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there are two ID columns (one from TABLE1, one from TABLE2) you can't use `SELECT *...` in this cursor or you'll get something like

```
ORA-06550: line 7, column 9: PLS-00402: alias required in SELECT list of
                             cursor to avoid duplicate column names
```

(at least in Oracle 11.2).

Try the following:

```
PROCEDURE testproc IS
  CURSOR cur1 IS
    Select t1.ID, t1.COLx, t2.COLy
      From table1 t1,
           table2 t2
      where table1.id = table2.id;

  l_var  cur1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur1;

  LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO l_var; 
    EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID=' || l_var.ID ||
                         'COLx=' || l_var.COLx ||
                         'COLy=' || l_var.COLy);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END testproc;
```

I included columns `COLx` and `COLy` in the cursor SELECT list as I don't know what what columns you actually have on your tables - replace them with whatever makes sense.

Share and enjoy.